# Make list of unicode words that are in a file

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

My code is

```
f = codecs.open(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\nepali.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8')
nepali = f.read().split()
for i in nepali:
    print i
```

Display the words in file:

```
यो
किताब
टेबुल
मा
छ
यो
एक
किताब
हो
केटा
```

But when I try to create a list of the words with code:

```
file=codecs.open(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\nepali.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8')
nepali = list(file.read().split())
print nepali
```

The output now is displayed like this

```
[u'\ufeff\u092f\u094b', u'\u0915\u093f\u0924\u093e\u092c', u'\u091f\u0947\u092c\u0941\u0932', u'\u092e\u093e', u'\u091b', u'\u092f\u094b', u'\u090f\u0915', u'\u0915\u093f\u0924\u093e\u092c', u'\u0939\u094b',]
```

The output should look like:

```
[यो, किताब, टेबुल, मा, छ,यो, एक, किताब, हो]
```

Comment: Note that Python 3 will display Unicode in lists if the character is printable: `['\ufeffयो', 'किताब', 'टेबुल', 'मा', 'छ', 'यो', 'एक', 'किताब', 'हो']`

Comment: The `'\ufeff'` in the first string is a byte order mark (BOM).  `utf-8-sig` codec will automatically detect and remove it when reading from a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the output of the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr), which is always used for displaying the contents of containers. The output is meant for debugging, not end-user displays; any non-printable non-ASCII codepoint is represented by an escape sequence (which can, depending on the codepoint, be a single character escape like `\t` or `\n`, or use 2, 4, or 8 hex digits, like `\xe5`, `\u2603` or `\U0001f4e2`).

You'll have to produce the output manually:

```
print u'[{}]'.format(u', '.join(nepali))
```

This produces a unicode string formatted to look like a list object, but without using `repr()`, simply by adding square brackets around the strings, joined with `', '` (comma and space).

Demo:

```
>>> nepali = [u'\ufeff\u092f\u094b', u'\u0915\u093f\u0924\u093e\u092c', u'\u091f\u0947\u092c\u0941\u0932', u'\u092e\u093e', u'\u091b', u'\u092f\u094b', u'\u090f\u0915', u'\u0915\u093f\u0924\u093e\u092c', u'\u0939\u094b',]
>>> print u'[{}]'.format(u', '.join(nepali))
[यो, किताब, टेबुल, मा, छ, यो, एक, किताब, हो]
```

However, if you want to show this to an end-user, why use the square brackets at all?